# Location header missing in the GDrive resumable upload response

Tags: google-drive-api

I followed the instructions at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload for resumable file uploads.

I have a working token for a service account (I verified I can list files) and do

```
$ curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
-H "Content-Length: 50" \
-H "X-Upload-Content-Type: application/pdf" \
-H "X-Upload-Content-Length: 1560010" -X POST \
'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable' \
-d '{"name": "myObject","mimeType": "application/pdf"}'
```

I should get an empty response and a Location header with the URL to use to upload my file. Instead I get no Location header and a response body pointing to the new file

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Mon, 31 Jul 2017 10:40:37 GMT
Vary: X-Origin
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,36,35"
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "0B8f3X4o60bqnWjU5aFIxbHB1bTA",
 "name": "myObject",
 "mimeType": "application/pdf"
}
```

A curl to list the files confirms that the file is there:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"  \
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
...
{
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": "0B8f3X4o60bqnWjU5aFIxbHB1bTA",
"name": "myObject",
"mimeType": "application/pdf"
},
...
```

I tried with wget and with Elixir's HTTPotion, same result. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[@noogui answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45429424/1505304) wasn't the solution because s/he didn't notice s/he gave two different URLs for the same operation. However seeing those two URLs close together made me realize that Google's documentation is wrong as it uses this in the text:

```
 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable
```

and this in the example:

```
 POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable
```

The first one is correct, the second one is wrong. I hope somebody from Google reads this and fixes the documentation.

I might say that using different URLs for file upload and for all the other file operations is bad design. Proof: even Google made a mistake picking the one to use in the example.

This is the correct response I get with the `/upload` URL:

```
$ curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"  \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
-H "Content-Length: 50" \
-H "X-Upload-Content-Type: application/pdf" \
-H "X-Upload-Content-Length: 1560010" \
-X POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable'  \
-d '{"name": "myObject","mimeType": "application/pdf"}'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-GUploader-UploadID: <upload-id>
Location: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=<upload-id>
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 06:37:02 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Server: UploadServer
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,36,35"
```

The Location header is there in the response.

I can upload a file now:

```
$ curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
-H "Content-Type: application/pdf" \
-H "Content-Length: 1560010" \
-X PUT 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=<upload-id>' \
--data-binary "@myObject.pdf"
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-GUploader-UploadID: <upload-id>
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 06:48:47 GMT
Content-Length: 118
Server: UploadServer
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,36,35"

{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "<file-id>",
 "name": "myObject",
 "mimeType": "application/pdf"
}
```

Proof that it worked:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token-id>" \
'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<file-id>?alt=media' \
> download.pdf
$ diff download.pdf myObject.pdf
$ echo $status
0
```

Note that it took a few minutes before the download succeeded. I got this error for the first attempts:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Vary: X-Origin
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error=invalid_token
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 06:56:35 GMT
Expires: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 06:56:35 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,36,35"
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Eventually consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format from the [Initiating a resumable upload session](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload#start-resumable) guide:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable
```

**Example: Initiating a resumable upload session**

The following example shows how to initiate a resumable session to upload a new file:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Upload-Content-Length: 2000000

{
  "name": "myObject"
}
```